# Subdivision of a continuous path so that every segment is contained in a open rectangle

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

I encountered the following passage in a book: let $\gamma$ be a continuous map from $[a,b]$ to an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then it is possible to subdivide the interval in to $a=t_0<t_1<\cdots t_n=b$, so that each subinterval is mapped by $\gamma$ into some open rectangle $R_i$ contained in $U$. Such a division exists by the Lebesgue lemma, since each point in the image of $\gamma$ is contained in some such rectangle.

I find this argument to be incomplete. It is true that each point in the image of $\gamma$ is contained in some open rectangle in $U$, and by compactness we have a finite family $(R_i)_{i\in I}$ of open rectangle in $U$ that covers the image of $\gamma$. But to obtain the required subdivision of $[a,b]$, I still need to argue as follows: for each $i\in I$, write $\gamma^{-1}(R_i)$ as the union of intervals of the form $[a,c)$ or $(c,d)$ or $(d,b]$. In this way we obtain an open covering of $[a,b]$ by such intervals. Of this covering, take a finite subcovering $(I_j)_{j\in J}$. Let $P$ be the set of endpoints of $(I_j)_{j\in J}$. Let $Q$ be the union of $P$ with the set of midpoints of two consecutive points in $P$. Then the points in $Q$ gives the desired subdivision $t_i$.

Do we have to argue as I did above or is there a simpler argument? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have ignored the Lebesgue lemma mentioned in the book. It enables this conclusion without any work. Let $\{U_i\}$ be the cover of $U$ consisting of given rectangles. Let $l$ be the Lebesgue number of the covering $\{U_i\}$ -- by definition this is the number such that any set of diameter less than $l$ lies in some $U_i.$ It exists by Lebesgue Covering Lemma. Then any subdivision $a=t_0<t_1<\cdots t_n=b $ will work as long as $\text{diam}f([t_i,t_{i+1}]) \leq l.$ $f$ is uniformly continuous, so such subdivisions exist.